# How to add more fields in facet other than default ones using SOLR?

Tags: php, solr

How to add more fields in facet other than default ones using SOLR? Like solr is returning that facet field and count in the facet but i want to get other fields also along with the facets. Please help

For Eg:- If i have to make a category facet, the SOLR  will return only category name and count in the facet. so if i want to add one more field like category_id also with that facet how can i do that?

Edit :-  I want category facets like this format.

category: [
            {
                name: "Mobiles",
                numDocs: 1002,
                category_id: 1719
            },
            {
                name: "Batteries",
                numDocs: 543,
                category_id: 1533,
            }
        ]

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the [facet parameters documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting)?

I cannot quite understand your question, but I suspect looking at **facet.query** and tagging and excluding filters may be the right direction to research.

Comment: please check question now for clarification

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use "appends" instead of "defaults" in the solrconfig file

This is an example:

```
 <lst name="appends">
     <str name="facet.field">field1</str>
     <str name="facet.field">field2</str>
 </lst>
```

The point is that with any section marked as "defaults", it means that these are the default values, and if the value is not provided in the URL the default value is used. However if the value is passed through the URL then these values are ignored.

What you need to do as I understand is the other way around. You want to provide an optional value from the url, and still be able to append values from the config file.
So, in this case you put your configurations in a "appends" section, not "defaults". Because defaults are overwritten by url params.

Cheers.

Comment: what will be the solr query to append fields to url? can you give me some example

Comment: sorl query would be as usual, and u just add additional parameters, ex: server/core/select?q=whatever&facet.field=field3